# ESS folding for R6 classes

Tags: init-file, customize, ess, code-folding, r

What is the proper way to install, configure and activate folding of R script files?

I followed [emacswiki.org/emacs/FoldingMode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FoldingMode) but it doesn't seems to work. I installed `folding.el` to `.emacs/lisp/`. I tried to define folding as `{` and `}` as you would expect in R. I work a lot with R6 classes, so folding body of methods is quite essential for navigation in class definition.
My current config for folding:

```
; folding
(add-to-list 'load-path' "~/.emacs.d/lisp/")
(load "folding" 'nomessage 'noerror)
(folding-mode-add-find-file-hook)
(folding-add-to-marks-list 'r-mode "{" "}" nil t)
```

Ideally I would like to replicate RStudio folding in Emacs ESS.